# Double gang three-way light fitting not working as it should

Tags: wiring

This light switch controls both down up and downstairs lights. Also, I have a second one upstairs that controls upstairs plus bathroom, and there is a single three-way switch downstairs.

There are 8 wires:

- grey wire brown sleeve
- black wire brown wire
- brown wire
- brown wire
- grey wire brown sleeve with a brown wire
- black wire brown sleeve with a brown wire

Six terminals on the switch. One side of the switch is working but the other side won’t control upstairs anymore. I’m in the UK.

[image]

Comment: Is this a new switch? Do you have pictures of the original wiring?

Comment: Sharon, I've updated some of your post to indicate _three-way_ switches, which is what I assume you meant. Please revise if that's not correct.

Comment: @isherwood The UK phrase for 3-way is 2-way.

Comment: never took photos or noted down anything , what a 